# Change the color of the arrow of the tooltip in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a class="nav-link fs-4 fw-medium p-1 m-1 text-light active" 
data-bs-toggle="tooltip" 
data-bs-placement="left"
 data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip" 
data-bs-title="You are already on Home Page"
 aria-current="page" href="#"> Home  </a>
<!-- CSS -->
tooltip-inner {
    background-color: red;
}
.tooltip-arrow {
border-color: red;
}
I have tried:
.custom-tooltip .tooltip-arrow::before {
    border-color: red;
}
.custom-tooltip .tooltip-arrow::after {
    border-color: red;
}
```

I want to change the color of the arrow of the tooltip using Bootstrap v5.3. How can I?

Comment: just try this `.tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
  border-top-color: #ff0000; /* Replace #ff0000 with your desired color */
}`  with hex code